# Default settings for imported materials in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, model

My problem is that when I import a model with .obj, .mtl, .png files, unity automatically creates a Material folder with materials inside.

I am bored of configuring the materials one by one, so is there a way of setting the default parameters of the newly created materials?

(Currently it is Opaque, 0 Metallic, 0.5 Smoothness, and I want to set for example the default smoothness to 0)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/default-import-settings-for-images-meshes.42856/
AND http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/can-i-change-the-default-import-settings.50043/ Sometimes it helps to google before posting on SO. All the best!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a full explanation in the documentation.

Comment: I found some info about enabling metallic keyword, but i couldn't find out what's that method's name, which is called after automatically reating a material. And also I couldn't figure out how these enable keyword things work :(